# Django Query to select multiply count

Tags: django, orm

Can any member can help to solve the bellow particular problem:

```sql
select 
    count(total_lead),
    count(pending),
    count(progress),
    count(closed) 
from
    leads
where 
    user=user
```

How do I achieve this query in Django ORM ? Any help in highly appreciated.

Thanks
Regards,

Comment: Hello, show us your Model first please.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you have shown us the model but assuming your model fields you can do something like:

```
leads.objects.all().annotate(Count('total_lead')).annotate(Count('pending')).annotate(Count('progress')).annotate(Count('closed'))
```